# RDPing to VMWare Machine, RDP from there doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, vmware

Im connecting to a VM (on a vmware vcenter) via RDP. From there, opening a RDP connection to another host (something which works fine if i use my desktop GUI to log on to the VM) doesn't work.
The RDP application window hangs indefinitely and I have to close it using Task Manager.
Any ideas why this happens? My host is W10, the VM is W7 and the remote host im connecting to is Windows Server 2008 R2 (I think).

I've looked at the event log for the system but nothing is being logged afaik. There's not much help to find online either

Comment: I would guess that there is a version mismatch for RDP. Try to ensure that RDP is the same version on all computers. You could also try running `mstsc /admin` on one or both.

Comment: I'm getting around it by first logging on to the local VM, starting an RDP session, then RDPing to that VM, and the other remote session is active and working.. Very strange.